# "AND" or "OR" in filterMetadata in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to filter out only the leap years from my imageCollection using the `'system:index'` property:

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-3.1929991656897982, 57.196020922235135],
          [-3.2808897906897982, 57.05289582927173],
          [-2.9732726031897982, 57.05289582927173]]]);


var chirps = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY")
            .filterDate('1981-12-31','2019-01-01')
            .filterBounds(polygon) 
var leapYears1 = allYearsChirps.filterMetadata('system:index','contains',('2016' || '2012' || '2008' || '2004' || '2000' || '1996' || '1992' || '1988' || '1984'))
```

Is it just not possible to filter for multiple strings, or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use ee.Filter.or( 'filter')  or use ee.Filter.inList(property, list):

First, set the years as strings to each image:

```
var setYears = chirps.map(function(image){
  return image.set('year', ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY'));
});
```

Then filter using one of the filters:

```
var leapYears = setYears.filter(ee.Filter.inList('year', 
          ee.List(['2016', '2012', '2008', '2004', '2000','1996','1992','1988','1984'])));
print(leapYears)
var leapYears1 = setYears.filter(ee.Filter.or(
  ee.Filter.eq('year','2016'), ee.Filter.eq('year','2012'), ee.Filter.eq('year','2008')));
print(leapYears1)
```

[link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7862ffa7ef56d4ed1c7ef6c394209b00)

Comment: Yeah, I kinda forgot mapping was a thing... Thanks for the help!